# How to bind model variable to input file type control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Working in asp.net mvc4:

I am implementing edit functionality. for that I need to mapping old values to model in controller and that model I am passing to view. In view I am unable to bind model variable to input file type control.
So want to know how to achieve this problem.

thanks in advance........

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want to have the value of the input file control set to a value in your model.

You cannot do this, due to security reasons.  Otherwise you could set the control to "c:\passwords.txt" or something, and use a bit of javascript to upload the file without the user knowing you have done so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with a a little jquery and HTML 5 compliant browser.

```
 $('#YourFormId').submit(function () {
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        cache: false,
        type: this.method,
        data: formData,
        success: function (result) {

        },
        beforeSend: function (e) {

        },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    // it is important to return false in order to 
    // cancel the default submission of the form
    // and perform the AJAX call
    return false;
});
```

I got this code from some where else, probably this site. I keep seeing people say you can't do this but it works in IE 10+ and Chrome.

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
    public class MyModel
{
    public string mytest { get; set; }
    public string mytest2 { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase  fileupload {get;set;}
}
```

Action looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YourActionName(YourModel model)
    {
        return whatever();
    }
```